# Set Html5 Datepicker value from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, datepicker

I can set the value to today'd date, but I can't seem to set the value based on a custom date string. I've shown in the code below the idea of what I want to do.

I have to use the string format of date that I specified below so that can't be changed, but can the format of the date string be modified?

```js
var newDate = new Date();    
newDate = "30/03/2020 12:00:00 AM";

$('#datePickerId').val(newDate);
```

---

```
error:
jquery.min.js:4 The specified value "30/03/2020 12:00:00 AM" does not 
conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".
```

Comment: You're creating a new `Date` variable, then immediately overwriting it with a string. Either use a string in the first place, in the correct format (i.e., `var newDate = '2020-03-30;`) or set the date variable correctly (i.e., `var newDate = new Date(2020, 2, 30);` [JavaScript months are 0-based]).

Comment: I understand that, but what I need to know is if there's a smart way to change the date format? I hard coded that date to make the example as simple as possible but in my project, I'm stuck working with that format. I don't want to get messy with substrings if I can help it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Are you able to use a library like moment.js or fecha.js?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in following 2 ways.
newDate1 : Javascript datetime 
newDate2:  moment js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var newDate1 = new Date(2020,03,30);    
console.log(newDate1);
var mm = newDate1.getMonth();
var dd = newDate1.getDate();
var aa = newDate1.getFullYear() +"-" + (mm < 10? "0":"") +mm +"-" + (dd < 10? "0":"") + dd;
$('#datePickerId1').val(aa);

var newDate2 = moment("30/03/2020 12:00:00 AM","DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
//console.log(newDate2);
$('#datePickerId2').val(newDate2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>


<h1>Show a date control:</h1>

  First: <input type="date" name="bday" id=datePickerId1><br/>
  Second: <input type="date" name="bday" id=datePickerId2>
```